# How does the ignition angle determine if a B2C works as a rectifier or inverter?

Tags: power-electronics

So I in my text it says that when I have an ignition angle between 0° and 90° my power converter (B2C) works as a rectifier generating a positive output voltage. If I have an ignition angle over 90° it works in "inverter mode" as long there is a power source on the DC side.

I don't understand how this works and I also have issues imagining how it looks like. Any ideas?

[image: B2C]

Comment: You need to give us a lot more context and datasheet links! What is a B2C? Add it into your question - **not in the comments**.